# MathJAX Arabic Mathematical unicode characters are not shown

Tags: html, unicode, mathjax

I'm trying to use [Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1EE00.pdf) in MathML
but it's not shown correctly with MathJAX, is there any specific font or MathJAX Configuration to render it properly?

here's a sample:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>MathJax Test</title>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            MathML: {
                extensions: ["mml3.js"] // required for rtl to be properly rendered (experimental extension)
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <p>Problem:</p>
    <math display="block" dir="rtl">
        <mrow>
            <mi>&#126492;</mi>
            <mo>&leq;</mo>
            <mi>&#126498;</mi>
        </mrow>
    </math>
    <p>Expected:</p>
    <p dir="rtl">&#126492; &leq; &#126498;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=before#using-in-line-configuration-options) explains that the inline configuration needs to be inserted *before* MathJax itself is loaded. Also, the "expected" result is rendered incorrectly in Chrome 46. MathJax, on the other hand, renders the expression correctly for me. I.e., First , then .

Comment: for some reason they appear as squares for me, seems a missing font issue.

Comment: Yes, that could be the result of the browser not finding a fallback font. I see the same on a mobile browser for example. It can also be a browser bug; we've seen various issues regarding fonts and text elements in SVG in the past.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.